# Is there a private API to read another app badge number?

Tags: ios, iphone-privateapi

I want to be able to read badge numbers from 3rd party apps.

I checked SpringBoardServiceService and found only `SBGetBadgeNumber` which is for reading your own badge number (it's used by higher level API `[UIApplication applicationIconBadgeNumber]`)

Any ideas?

Usual disclaimer: This application won't be distributed through AppStore and it's for research purposes only.

Comment: `SBGetBadgeNumber` doesn't take any arguments?   I thought I saw that the **setter** allowed you to pass in a bundle ID.  Not true with the getter?

Comment: Actually, you could be right. It gets 2 parameters (first port and second - some unknown parameter). UIKit passes 0 to second parameter, but may be I can pass bundle ID or something like that. Let me check that. For some reason, I ignored this second parameter and made a connection that applicationIconBadgeNumber is just higher level SBGetBadgeNumber.

Comment: Actually, let me take a back. And I think, it's time to go and watch TV, instead of looking at disassembler. SBGetBadgeNumber second parameter receives a pointer to an integer through which it returns badge count for current application. So, It's for current application only.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this isn't possible, at least on a non-jailbroken device. iOS apps are sandboxed from each other and can't read each other's data.

Comment: That's not 100% true. Yes, they are sandboxed. However, sandbox isn't bulletproof. There are A LOT of private API's which allow to access some additional information (which isn't accesible through public API)

Comment: Good point. Just because it would get rejected by the App Store doesn't mean it's impossible :-)